# Import text file data into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis-2012

I have a text file with below format

[image]

I want to import it in SQL Server database by splitting it into several columns:

```
Terminal, NetSales, NetAjustment, CancelsCnt, CancelAmount, 
CashesCnt, CashesAmount, ClaimsCnt, ClaimsAmount, SalesCommission, 
CashCommission, NetDue
```

I have tried to insert the text file in SQL Server using SSIS but its inserting everything in one column instead of split it, then used SQL scripting to split it into several columns but its not working

I'm having some difficulties to split the column from the text file

Any ideas or help about how I can capture those columns data into a proper format?

Comment: This isn't a delimited file so you can't use splitting, with any tool. You can import the data with SSIS if you skip all rows up to the first data row and specify fixed width columns. You'll have to do the same no matter what tool you use

Comment: Please post your SSIS jobs details/configurations so we can further help you.

Comment: "I have tried ... but its _[sic]_ not working." doesn't give us much to go on. Show us what you've tried and explain how it didn't meet your needs. Then we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use SSIS **Bulk Insert Task**.

[Bulk Insert Task in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/bulk-insert-task-in-ssis/)

It has identical functionality as a T-SQL `BULK INSERT` statement.

It allows to specify where real first row starts via its `FIRSTROW` parameter.

Here is a conceptual example.

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl (
   Terminal VARCHAR(20),
   NetSales VARCHAR(30),
   NetAjustment VARCHAR(100),
   CancelsCnt INT
   ...
);

BULK INSERT dbo.tbl
FROM 'e:\Temp\inputFile.csv'
WITH (FORMAT='CSV'
   , DATAFILETYPE = 'char' -- { 'char' | 'native' | 'widechar' | 'widenative' } 
   , FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t' -- for a TAB
   , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
   , FIRSTROW = 8 
   , CODEPAGE = '65001');

-- test
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl;
```